# How to set style/theme for a ViewGroup

Tags: android

Can someone tell me **how to set a style for a ViewGroup CLASS**? I've tried to find solution in internet but didn't succeed.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what did you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    style="@style/AppTheme"  // <--------- reference your style here
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I meant ViewGroup Class, sorry for disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

define style in style.xml file in your res folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="Style_Button_SquareGrayLight">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_basic_gray_rounded_corners</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dip</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

as given above my style name is "Style_Button_SquareGrayLight" and now you can set this style to any view or viewgroup using style="@style/AppThemeName" property as below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/page_left_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/page_top_padding"
style="@style/Style_Button_SquareGrayLight"/>
```

similarly you can set for views like Button,TextView etc too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I meant ViewGroup **class** sorry for disappointing.